# How to change the start url phonegap duo to app setting?

Tags: android, cordova

I'm new to using phonegap

I want to create an android application using phonegap.
I want to load different starting page that is when running the program for the first time I want to run URL1 (that allows the user to set app configs) and on subsequent runs I want to run URL2 (that loads the current settings)

How can I do that??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use below code;

```
if(first)
super.loadUrl("URL1");
else
super.loadUrl("URL2");
```

on your `onCreate()` method.
Put the 'first' parameter in `SharedPreferences` as a flag to detect first run.